# data table out of memory exception

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

We have lots of old excel files that contain quite a bit of data. I am trying to get this data into SQL Server.

I have a C# application that I have used before to upload data from excel to SQL, the code is shown below.

The excel sheet has dates going across the sheet in row 4. The first date is in cell D4. There are id's (strings) going down from cell A5 to A11005. The values are of type double.

I am getting a System.OutOfMemoryException exception. I am surprised though as this error has been thrown on the 10,785<sup>th</sup> row & 333<sup>rd</sup> column. Is it really out of memory? I thought this wouldn't be a huge amount of data to be honest for a data table.

11,000 ids, 785 dates so 8,635,000 doubles. Is Visual Studio out of memory? I have a 64 bit PC with 32 GB RAM.

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("DateTM", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Vtm", typeof(double));

            OpenExcelWorkbook(path + fileName, true);

            XlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)XlWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
            Rng = XlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            object[,] valueArray = (object[,])Rng.get_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
            XlWorkbook.Close(false);

            // dates start in cell D4
            DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[valueArray.GetLength(1) - 3];

            for (int t = 4; t <= valueArray.GetLength(1); t++)
                dates[t - 4] = Convert.ToDateTime(valueArray[4, t]);

            // values start from row 5
            for (int n = 5; n <= valueArray.GetLength(0); n++)
            {
                string id = valueArray[n, 1].ToString().Trim();

                // dates start from column D
                for (int m = 4; m <= valueArray.GetLength(1); m++)
                {
                    double vt = Convert.ToDouble(valueArray[n, m]);

                    if (vt == -2146826246)     // for any #N/A values
                        vt = -999;

                    dt.Rows.Add(dates[m - 4], id, vt);
                }
            }

            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(UtilityLibrary.Database.Connections.Myconnection))
            {
                sqlBulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "tblMyTbl";
                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dt);
            }
```

Comment: Ensure that the process is `x64` and **not** `Any CPU` (tends to pick `x86`). Also, how big is the actual file?

Comment: Are you running it as 64-bit process? Check your build configuration. What is the platform target? Do you have "prefer 32-bit" checked?

Comment: @odyss-jii Ah I see Prefer 32-bit is indeed checked. Will uncheck it now.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I see the platform target (is that the process you are talking about?) is indeed any cpu. Will change to x64

Comment: thanks camilo & odyss it is now working. Happy to mark as correct if you put the solution as an answer